# django-cms: ImportError: No module named 'cms.models'

Tags: python, windows, django-cms

I tried to update django-cms and now I get an error:

```
from cms.models import CMSPlugin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'cms.models'
```

It seems that the package is corrupted.  I tried uninstalling to reinstall, but I get an error in the uninstall:
Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 527, in move
os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'c:\\users\\rando\\ops3\\lib\\site-packages\\cms\\test_utils\\project\\extensionapp\\migrations\\__pycache__\\0003_multitablepageextension_multitablepageextensionparent_multitabletitleextension_multit
abletitleextens.cpython-34.pyc' -> 'C:\\Users\\rando\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-z4by4lt8\\users\\rando\\ops3\\lib\\site-packages\\cms\\test_utils\\project\\extensionapp\\migrations\\__pycache__\\0003_multitablepageextension_multitablepageextensionparent_multitablet
itleextension_multitabletitleextens.cpython-34.pyc'
```

If I try to install - it believes it is already there.

Any suggestions on how to reinstall the package?

Comment: If it can't find `cms` to import then that suggests your `PATH` is missing your `site-packages` directory.

Comment: @markwalker_ Thanks, I'll explore that.  It's odd, as I have many site packages, and I'm not having a problem seeing the others.  Oddly, there is no django_cms directory, just the .dist_info directory.  It's like it never got unpacked.  But I don't know how to force that.